# How to setup Opengl in Dev C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using Dev C++ 5.1.1
I have watched many YouTube videos about setting up Opengl but none of them worked for me.I don't have some folders that they have in their videos. I installed dev c++ in default setting and the thing I only change is the installation location.Can anybody share link for downloading Opengl and how to setup it in Dev C++.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dev-C++ is a bit outdated, but I would recommend looking into GLUT, the OpenGL Utility Toolkit system.
You can follow these steps as described on https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-OpenGL-in-DEV-C++

1. Download this small zip file from here, it contains GLUT , libraries and header files http://www.mediafire.com/?34171u995goq9ci
2. extract the zip file and place it in any desired folder.
3. Open a file named “glut-7.6-3.DevPak” and let it execute.
4. As soon as “glut-7.6-3.DevPak” has finished its work, do the following steps:
   File->New->Project
   Click on Multimedia and select GLUT

OR

File->New->Project
Click “Empty project”, Give it a desired name and save it in any folder .

5. (Skip this if you’ve chosen glut project in step no. 4 ) Now right click on your project and click “New File”., You will see an “untitled” file.
6. (Skip this if you’ve chosen glut project in step no. 4 )Now paste the following code in that untitled file:(main.cpp)
7. Now press F9 i.e. Compile and Run. you will see many linker errors dont worry, its just because we didnt link our project with the libraries of OpenGL and GLUT.
8. Now goto menu-bar (That “File, edit and help” toolbar ) and click on Project->Project properties. Or you can use keyboard shortcut “Alt + P”.
9. Click on “Parameters” then click on “Add Library or Object” button.
10. Point your browser to “lib” folder in those extracted folder.
11. Now add these lines in starting of your Linker textbox:

`-lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32`

and in Compiler textbox add

`-DGLUT_STATIC`

12. Now you can finally press F9 and see a small rectangle in window.

So now you have made a project with OpenGL linked to it.

Comment: What is OpenGL Utility Tool kit?

Comment: OpenGL Utility Toolkit (GLUT) is a library of utilities for OpenGL programs, which primarily perform system-level I/O with the host operating system. Functions performed include window definition, window control, and monitoring of keyboard and mouse input. (from Wikipedia)

Comment: From where to download it?And thanks. : )

Comment: @h4le5torm: GLUT is terribly outdated. Use FreeGLUT instead, which at least is actively maintained. Also the API is pretty limited and as soon as things become a little bit more complex you're running into walls. I recommend using GLFW instead of GLUT. Also GLU is limited to old-and-busted fixed function pipeline OpenGL. – In short, everything you recommend would have made sense 20 years ago, but we've moved on since then.

Comment: How to download free glut?

Comment: With a simple google search, you can find FreeGLUT on SourceForge's website.